# Decrypting EFS files on a non-bootable former windows drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, efs, decryption

There are many questions like this one but this one is mine. Here is the situation:

I had some valuable files on my Windows 10 system that I encrypted with windows built-in EFS. Now that drive has became unbootable (which I think was because of a BIOS upgrade but either way) and I want those files on my current windows drive. I've tried a bunch of fixes to get windows working again but for whatever reason I don't think that is possible.

The file system is exactly the same as it was when it was still bootable and I still know the user name and password. I can find the keys and everything but I don't know how to turn them into keys that I can use to decrypt the files. I also don't have permission to move the files which makes things more difficult I think.

I know that there may not be an easy solution but I am willing to do this the hard way if you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks for the advice!

PS I tried using elcomsoft's Advanced EFS Data Recovery (free version) which said it worked but the "decrypted" files aren't properly decrypted and seem to be corrupt (this is a new copy, the old files are unchanged). So I don't think that worked.

Comment: Unfourtantly if you didn't already make a backup of the keys used to encrypt your files it's extremely likely you are up the creek without a paddle.  **If you actually do have a backup of the certificate that was created when you enabled EFS you should be able to just import that certificate.**  You will have to take ownership of files depending on their location on the old disk.

Comment: @Ramhound: OP does mention that they still have all the key files that CryptoAPI had stored, so _in theory_ it should be possible for a recovery program to imitate what Windows does (use the password to find and unlock the master key, then use it to unlock the stored certificate keys)... I don't know any such programs, but I strongly suspect they might be branded as generic "CryptoAPI certificate/key recovery" tools, not specifically EFS recovery tools.

Comment: This is only possible if you have exported the EFS certificate **and the private key**. You need to have a backup of the full `.pfx` certificate file and to import it on the new system, before being able to decrypt the drive. There is also the unknown question of whether the disk is in a good enough shape for decrypting. Encryption is a dangerous tool when used without enough safeguards, and especially backups.

Comment: @user1686 - I can almost guarantee that the author didn’t backup the private key.